# Prepend text to Text file using VBScript

Tags: vbscript

I have this script to allow me to insert text into a text file but I need it to be at the start of the text file. This script currently adds this to the end of the .txt file.
And I am new to trying these things out myself

```
Option Explicit
Dim objFSO, objFolder, objShell, objTextFile, objFile
Dim strDirectory, strFile, strText
strDirectory = "c:\scripts"
strFile = "\csv.txt"
strText = "sep=|"

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

If objFSO.FolderExists(strDirectory) Then
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strDirectory)
Else
  Set objFolder = objFSO.CreateFolder(strDirectory)
  WScript.Echo "Just created " & strDirectory
End If

If objFSO.FileExists(strDirectory & strFile) Then
   Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strDirectory)
Else
   Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(strDirectory & strFile)
   Wscript.Echo "Just created " & strDirectory & strFile
End If

set objFile = nothing
set objFolder = nothing

Const ForAppending = 8

Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile _
(strDirectory & strFile, ForAppending, True)

objTextFile.WriteLine(strText)
objTextFile.Close

WScript.Quit
```

Comment: Please have a look at [this checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)
and try to edit your question to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Up to now your question is kind of vague, making it hard to see what you are doing and where the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read the file's content into a string, add your string in front of that and write everything back to the same file.

```
Dim sFileText
Dim sPrependText
Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2

' Open file For Reading and Read All content to a variable
Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile (strDirectory & strFile, ForReading, True)
sFileText = objTextFile.ReadAll
objTextFile.Close

' Prepend text in front of file's content
sPrependText = "sep=|"
sFileText = sPrependText & sFileText

' Open file For Writing and write text variable
Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile (strDirectory & strFile, ForWriting, True)
objTextFile.Write sFileText
objTextFile.Close
```

Comment: OK so what am I missing here to be honest I am not sure where to add this or edit AKA newbie

Comment: This code would go after your `Const ForAppending = 8` line (keep that line) and would replace everything up to `WScript.Quit`.